# Where to obtain opera mini ip list for nginx geo module?

Tags: proxy, nginx, geolocation, opera-mini

I need proxy ip address of Opera Mini to use it in Geo module (nginx). Nginx can automatically use X-FORWARDED-FOR header for proxies, but where to get proxy list?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand exactly what problem you want to solve, but I assume you want to implement some geolocation feature for the end-user and your question is about what IP address to use.

If so, please see the documentation for Opera Mini request headers and X-Forwarded-For:
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/opera-mini-request-headers/

> X-Forwarded-For
>
> This contains a comma-separated list of the proxy servers the request has passed on its way from the device to the Mini proxy. The first item in the list that is not an internal IP will always be the IP address that connects to the Mini proxy, hence it is the most reliable source of information about the origin of the request, and is suitable for geolocation etc.

Comment: Nginx requires a list of proxy. If ip in the list, nginx gets X-Forwared-For header

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find the official list anywhere on opera website. Here is [some of those ips](http://my.opera.com/jeni271/blog/show.dml/17001232)

[EDIT] Removed one paragraph of my original answer here, because that could be misleading. After reading the nginx GeoIP source code, it seems necessary to know all of the 'trusted' opera mini proxies such that nginx GeoIP module can get an IP behind those proxies using x-forwarded-for header.

Comment: if I use 
proxy 0.0.0.0/0 
to tell nginx to parse x-forwarded-for for any ip address, would it be acceptable?

Comment: AFAIK, it should work if you don't mind fraud (any client can send x-forwarded-for header to trick your site think the traffic is from a different geo location).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Opera IP addresses are not already in MaxMind database? (that's the DB that the nginx module uses by default)

My first bet would be to think that those IP addresses are going to be in MaxMind list, being proxies or not.

But I think that the best thing to do is a quick test using opera proxies and another proxies from any public [HTTP proxy list](http://proxy-ip-list.com/) resource. Then verify if you're getting the geo location of your proxy IP or not.

Remember to configure Nginx to use the x-forwarded-for IP for the geo location.

```
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
```

Then a simple example for testing could be:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>What is my IP address - determine or retrieve my IP address</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <?php
     if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
        $pipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "Your Proxy IP address is : ".$pipaddress. " (via $ipaddress) " ;
    } else {
        $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
        echo "Your IP address is : $ipaddress";
    }
    $country = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_NAME);
    $country_code = getenv(GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE);
    echo "<br/>Your country : $country ( $country_code ) ";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

(I just copy/paste that example from another site but I think that's well done)

Comment: This does not seem to work for me in opera mini, the ip i get is a US ip address yet am in a different location, other browsers are ok.

Answer (score 0):

Proxy (but really MITM) servers for Opera Mini and Opera Turbo reside in "Opera Software AS" IP address blocks, which include:

```
    37.228.104.0 255.255.248.0
    82.145.208.0 255.255.240.0
    107.167.96.0 255.255.224.0
    141.0.8.0 255.255.248.0
    185.26.180.0 255.255.252.0
```